# Is there any way to estimate this functions: $f(n)=\sum_{d|n}d\varphi(d)$ and $g(n)=\sum_{d|n}\frac{\varphi(d)}{d}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-number-theory

Let that $n$ be a natural number and $\varphi(n)$ be the Euler totient function. Is there any formula or estimation for computing functions $f,g$ such that:
$$
f(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d\varphi(d)
$$
and
$$
g(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\varphi(d)}{d}.
$$
For $n=p$ as the prime number it is clear that $f(p)=p^2-p+1$ and $g(p)=\frac{2p-1}{p}$.
We know that $f(n)=o(n^{3+\epsilon})$ and $g(n)=o(n^{1+\epsilon})$  for $\epsilon>0$

Comment: It is very likely these functions behave fairly erratically. Are you interested in estimates of their average behavior, or upper and lower bounds?

Comment: Aren't these functions multiplicative? So you should be able to get everything from their values at prime powers, no?

Comment: A corresponding post on [math.se]: [Computing $f,g$ such that $f(n)=\sum_{d|n}d\varphi(d)$ and $g(n)=\sum_{d|n}\frac{\varphi(d)}{d}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4847654)

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov yes, as the Dirichlet convolution of two multiplicative functions

Comment: I'm confused when you write $o(f(n))=n^{3+\epsilon}$, since this seems false under the standard definition of little-oh. $n$ has at most $\tau(n)$ divisors, and $\tau(n)=o(n^{\epsilon})$, so $f(n) = o(n^{2+\epsilon})$.  Similarly, $g(n) \leq \tau(n)$ trivially, so $g(n) = o(n^{\epsilon})$. Do you mean something else by your notation here?

Comment: I believe

$$f(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n} d\, \phi(d)$$

corresponds to [OEIS entry A057660](https://oeis.org/A057660) for 

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{\gcd (n,k)}$$

and

$$g(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n} \frac{\phi(d)}{d}=\frac{P(n)}{n}$$

where

$$P(n)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \gcd(k,n)$$

is [Pillai's arithmetical function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillai%27s_arithmetical_function) corresponding to [OEIS Entry A018804](https://oeis.org/A018804).

There are additional formulas for $f(n)$ and $P(n)$ at the two OEIS entries linked above.

Comment: take a look at Nicolas 1983 http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Nicolas_1983.pdf

Comment: If I computed correctly, the Wiener Ikehara Theorem gives $\sum_{n\le x}f(n)\sim\frac{\zeta(3)}{\zeta(2)}x^3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was essentially observed by @StevenClark in the comments. Both functions are multiplicative with the following formulas:
$$f(n) = \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_i^{2d_i+1}+1}{p_i+1}$$
and
$$g(n) = \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_i(d_i+1)-d_i}{p_i},$$
where $n=p_1^{d_1}\dots p_k^{d_k}$ is the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: They are useful. Is there proof for these formulas?

Comment: @JamalFarokhi: Proof is simple given that summands are multiplicative functions themselves. For relatively prime $m,n$ we have $$f(mn) = \sum_{d_1|m} \sum_{d_2|n} d_1d_2\varphi(d_1d_2) = \sum_{d_1|m} d_1\varphi(d_1) \sum_{d_2|n} d_2\varphi(d_2) = f(m)f(n)$$
and similarly for $g$.

Comment: I tried to proof this formula but I unfortunately can't.

Comment: @JamalFarokhi: I gave a proof for $f$ in the comment above. A proof for $g$ is similar.

Comment: My main problem is to prove this two function:   $$f(n) = \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_i^{2d_i+1}+1}{p_i+1}$$
and
$$g(n) = \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_i(d_i+1)-d_i}{p_i},$$ My result is different.

Comment: @JamalFarokhi: I do not quite follow your concern. Note that the terms in products are simply $f(p_i^{d_i})$ and $g(p_i^{d_i})$, respectively, and so the formulas immediately follow from the multiplicativity proved above.